# CQRS pattern: using command for external api call

Tags: rest, cqrs

I am aware of CQRS pattern wherein Query to be used for Reading data and Command to be used for updating the data.

In a peculiar case where the rest api is POST but not updating the data directly rather calling an external POST api of other system and passing the details.

In such case which one holds true - use Query or Command?

**Update* *

System involves multiple DB. Not necessarily different DB for query and command however

Comment: POST not necessarily imply command. Some communication patterns (like SOAP, JSONRPC,...) operates only using POST and they might no involve commands, just reading of data.Answer to this question is opinion based imho

Comment: @rkosegi shouldn't post only use for creating the data by rest api design? This question is strictly for the rest apis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Super simple.  If you know for sure the call will not update or modify state or data, then it's a query, if it does (or might) then it's a command.

However, CQRS is often more about the physical structure of your system.  You might have separate command and query databases... and that complicates the answer.  It can have both logical and physical aspects.

Comment: Thanks @erik for your reply. Since this is post, ought to update the data but via some other external api call. I'll move it as a Command.

Comment: we have separate Db for multiple end systems but not exactly for different for query and command